# PDO(?) -- :variable

Tags: php, pdo

I found this code. 
How is it possible to use a variable (the delete command), before defining it? My understanding, at least - is that this sets :id to the value of $id.

```
    $this->db->query('DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id');
    $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
```

Comment: See also [What does a colon before a literal in an SQL statement mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14589407) and [Need Some Explanation of PHP PDO....!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12739398)

Answer (score 2):

Here, `:id` is not a variable, it's a named placeholder.

In the second statement, you just tell PDO to bind the value of `$id` with the `:id` placeholder.

See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `prepare`. Query makes only a query. So you have to prepare it first.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->execute(array('red'));
```

Something like that.

Comment: OPs example is not using the plain PDO interface but a wrapper; so there's no reason for `query` to not be an alias of `prepare` already.